# How big is pprof import overhead in go

Tags: go

I have a couple of go programs that have a unused inport of `net/http/pprof` in them.

```
import _ "net/http/pprof"
...
//http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:6060", nil)
```

I was wondering what the overhead of this import is in term of CPU and Mem. Aka. Should I remove then in prod (yes), but what would be the impact if I forgot?

Related: what are the exact sideeffects of this import? It registers some http handlers, but does it also inject things in go's malloc functions?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The overhead of importing the net/http/pprof package is pretty limited: it just installs some handlers for the http server. See the source code at:

http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/pprof/pprof.go

CPU profiling is not activated at initialization time, it is only activated for a period of time (30 seconds by default) when the /debug/pprof/profile REST service is called. So compiling with this package should not impact much the performance of the application (except that extra goroutines for the http server are needed).

Now, during the execution of /debug/pprof/profile, CPU sampling is activated, so a performance overhead is expected. I guess it can be used for production code provided the access to the corresponding port is restricted to the administrators of the application.

Comment: I have add that WHEN the CPU sampling is enabled, it is heavy. As in "will drop the performance of your application to 1% from the original" heavy. I would be myself squeamish of leaving a possibility of accidental activation around.

Comment: @user918176: Nonsense.

Comment: thanks @Didier for the info. Regarding `So compiling with this package should not impact much the performance of the application`, do you find any official doc on what could be the performance hit?

Comment: According to [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/continuous-profiling-of-go-programs-96d4416af77b), even profiling CPU 10 seconds every minute will lead to around 5% overhead max.