# is it ok to use golang pprof on production without effecting performance?

Tags: go, pprof

I'm kind of new to the `pprof` tool, and am wondering if its ok to keep running this in production.  From the articles I have seen, it seems to be ok and standard, however I'm confused as to how this does not affect performance since it does a sampling `N` times every second and how come this does not lead to a degradation in performance.

Comment: If you want to monitor use monitoring system and not pprof; pprof is for cases where you need to track down some issues and debug

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Jaana Dogan](https://twitter.com/rakyll) does say in her article "[Continuous Profiling of Go programs](https://medium.com/google-cloud/continuous-profiling-of-go-programs-96d4416af77b)"

> ### Profiling in production
>
> **pprof is safe to use in production**.
> **We target an additional 5% overhead for CPU and heap allocation profiling**.
>
> The collection is happening for 10 seconds for every minute from a single instance. If you have multiple replicas of a Kubernetes pod, we make sure we do amortized collection.
> For example, if you have 10 replicas of a pod, the overhead will be 0.5%. This makes it possible for users to keep the profiling always on.
>
> We currently support CPU, heap, mutex and thread profiles for Go programs.
>
> #### Why?
>
> Before explaining how you can use the profiler in production, it would be helpful to explain why you would ever want to profile in production. Some very common cases are:
>
> - Debug performance problems only visible in production.
> - Understand the CPU usage to reduce billing.
> - Understand where the contention cumulates and optimize.
> - Understand the impact of new releases, e.g. seeing the difference between canary and production.
> - Enrich your distributed traces by correlating them with profiling samples to understand the root cause of latency.

So if you are using `pprof` for the right reason, yes, you can leave it in production.
But for basic monitoring, as commented, the system is enough.

As noted in "[Continuous Profiling and Go](https://medium.com/@tvii/continuous-profiling-and-go-6c0ab4d2504b)" by [Vladimir Varankin](https://twitter.com/tvii)

> Depending on the state of the infrastructure in the company, an “unexpected” HTTP server inside the application’s process can raise questions from your systems operations department ;)
>
> At the same time, depending on the peculiar nature of a company, the very ability to access something inside a production application, that doesn’t directly relate to application’s business logic, can raise questions from the security department ;)) I

So the overhead is not the only criteria to consider when leaving active such a feature.

Comment: The article talks about AWS polling pprof every minute. That's where the 5% overhead is coming from. It doesn't mean an idle pprof has that much overhead.

Comment: @rustyx Agreed. I have seen your comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/26546682/6309 (which dates from 2014 though)